# Creating a fixed support button in laravel

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

i should create a fixed button in my home page.
means a button would have existed that when clicked that, a support page be opened above the button!

i saw some examples of this in web, but I can not use them, and I'm really confused, because the codes are embedded and have complex javascripts.

I request that you provide a resource to solve this problem.

Do not need to be too complicated, just functional and beautiful.

For example, the button is this:

[image: Button]

And page is this:

[image: Page]

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: That has nothing to do with Laravel. You could do that with jquery and bootstrap. It's not a big deal to learn this. This is front-end programming.

Comment: @hev1 I have no code now, i confused really.
If possible give me a source for this problem.
Thank you

Comment: @DimitriMostrey I know this problem solve with jquery, but unfortunately i can't solve this.
Do you have any source(link) or template for this?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @AbolfazlPourrezaeian: something like the bootstrap modal? http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#vertically-centered

Comment: @DavidLiang no, something like this:
https://www.finnlough.com/en/accommodation/bubblehouse

Comment: @DavidLiang or like these websites:
https://small.chat/ , 
https://www.livechatinc.com/blog/live-chat-customer-experience/ , 
https://www.leadfeeder.com/

Thanks

Comment: @AbolfazlPourrezaeian: See my post. I think you can achieve that by using bootstrap modal. Those sites use 3rd party chat plugin. You can do the same too but if you only want to figure out how to do similar things via bootstrap, modal is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via bootstrap modal. On bootstrap documentation site, there is an example where the modal is styled to center on the screen: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#vertically-centered.

You can apply custom styles to make it appear on the bottom right of the screen instead.

#### Structure

```
<header>
    <nav></nav>
</header>
<main></main>
<footer></footer>

<button id="support-modal-launcher" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#support-modal">
    Support
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="support-modal"></div>
```

#### Style

```
body {
    position: relative;
}

footer {
    padding: 2rem 0;
    margin-top: 3rem;
}

#support-modal-launcher {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 2rem;
    right: 2.5rem;
}

#support-modal .modal-dialog {
    margin-right: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    height: calc(100vh - (1.75rem * 2));
}
```

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/125639/

Of course, if you want to create something exactly like https://small.chat/, https://www.finnlough.com/en/accommodation/bubblehouse, https://www.livechatinc.com/blog/live-chat-customer-experience/ and https://www.leadfeeder.com/, you need to spend the time to create the style yourself.

Comment: Your solution was very good and I was able to solve my problem by your guidelines.

Thank you very much.